# How do I install LILO boot loader with Ubuntu and Windows dualboot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, bootloader, easybcd

I want to use the LILO boot loader so I can use EasyBCD to show a Ubuntu listing on the Windows Boot Manager screen, but I don't know how. Please make this as simple as possible, as I don't know much about Linux or LILO. My computer is only Legacy boot mode, no UEFI.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David I'm using Ubuntu verson 20.04